# ¿Que razones puede haber para que un servidor de Mysql se caiga ?

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para una empresa de mi país ya hace aproximadamente 5 meses. En ese tiempo, ha habido problemas con los servicios del Motor de Base de Datos de Mysql. Hay veces se oculta la DB o no deja acceso a ella. me gustaría saber sus opiniones respecto a esto. ¿Porque se podría caer el Motor de base de datos de Mysql? De ante mano muchas gracias.

Postdata: Uno de los errores comunes que sale cuando sucede esto es el error #1203 El servidor de MYSQL no autorizó su ingreso

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta mejor, pues si esta basada en opiniones deberas modificarla

Comment: Fuera util que agregaras que mas te dice el error 1203, su explicacion

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación oficial (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) podría ser un problema por el número de usuarios que tienes conectados a la base de datos (por defecto 151). Lo que yo haría es:

- Como medida de contención subiría el valor de conexiones
- Mientras tanto revisaría los procesos de que consumen datos de ese servidor y revisaría que no se queden activos más de la cuenta. Habitualmente ocurre que hay procesos que ocupan más tiempo de lo habitual y, cuando tienes más usuarios de lo esperado, empiezan a ocupar todas las conexiones disponibles y te paran el servidor.

En cualquier caso te recomendaría el uso de alguna herramienta de monitorización del servidor para saber realmente la carga que tiene tu servidor y si realmente estás teniendo más tráfico del que esperas.

Si todo está dentro de lo esperado, no te queda más remedio que aumentar las conexiones y vigilar los recursos del servidor (ram, disco...).

Answer (score 1):

Según leí el error #1203 ocurre porque se supera el numero máximo de usuarios conectados a la base de datos.

> Error: 1203 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_TOO_MANY_USER_CONNECTIONS)
>
> Message: User %s already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

En español:

> Error: 1203 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_TOO_MANY_USER_CONNECTIONS)
>
> Message: El Usuario %s ya tiene tiene mas conexiones activas que 'max_user_connections'

**La bases de datos tienen dos valores que limitan las conexiones:**

1) `max_connections`: maximo de conexiones permitas, por defecto `150`

2) `max_user_connections`: maximo de usuarios permitidos, por defecto `max_connections + 1`

Por defecto el maximo de conexion de mysql es 151 por motivos de eficiencia, y lo mas seguro es que esten ocupando todas las conexiones maximas que permite la BBDD, es por ello que deberias averiguar que elementos estan ocupando todas las conexiones,o en su defecto modificar esos valores para ampliar la capacidad.

**1ra Solucion:**

Por lo tanto deberias ir a: `MYSQL CONSOLE`

Luego colocar estos comandos para comprobar que ocurre:

```
show variables like "max_connections";

show variables like "max_user_connections";
```

Y luego modificar el valor de la conexione con:

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

(El ; punto y coma puede causarte o no error)

> OJO:

Toma en cuenta que el maximo numero de conexion esta basado en tu equipo fisico y depende de la RAM la cantidad maxima, puedes usar esta formula:

```
max.connection=(available RAM-global buffers)/thread buffers
```

**2da Solución:**

limitar las conexiones persistentes con el siguiente script en el "php.ini":

```
[MySQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

El máximo número de conexiones simultáneas corresponde al tipo de Sistema Operativo y de RAM disponibles, como así también a la versión de PHP y MySQL.

Con este script podras limitar las conexiones persistentes (Las conexiones persistentes son enlaces que no se cierran al finalizar la ejecución de un script.), los cuales podrian estar saturando a la BBDD